# Align TextView with EditText inside Relative layout

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, alignment, android-relativelayout

I saw some posts regarding alignment of `TextView` with `EditText` on Android canvas. But, I didn´t found answer which could help me in the right way. My desire is to have `TextView` and `EditText` in a following manner:

```
     (TextView) (EditText)          (TextView) (EditText)
     (TextView) (EditText)          (TextView) (EditText)
     (TextView) (EditText)          (TextView) (EditText)
     (TextView) (EditText)
```

`EditText` *width* and *height* are predefined (values given in dp). Also, *top* and *left margin* of **TextEdit** is given. That means that I have to place `EditText` of certain size and to certain position on the screen. This is ok, and I achieved it using one `RelativeLayout` container. 
But I should also put label(`TextView`) beside `EditText` in such a way that i don´t specify any value in dps, because textviews have to placed automatically with respect to `EditText`. For example

```
           Street: [Main Street] 
    Street Number: [     4     ]
```

I tried using Relative layout attributes:

```
  layout_alignTop="@id/EditText"
  layout_toLeftOf="@id/EditText"
```

But, TextView is not showed, because it is placed left of `EditText` but exactly on the left margin(top alignment works) and not "exactly" beside EditText (2dp or 3dp left from `EditText`) like I want.
I also tried other attributes but no result.

1. Is there some native android attribute for putting labels near `EditText` like i want?
2. Is there some attribute in Relative layout that can do job for me?
3. Is there way just to specify that `TextView` is 3 dp left from `EditText`?
4. Any other solutions?

Thanks

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText1"
    android:hint="Write..."
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_dropdown_light_frame"/>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/EditText1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/EditText1"/>

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText2"
    android:hint="Write..."
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="490dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_dropdown_light_frame"/>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/EditText2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/EditText2" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you show your xml layout code

Comment: Ok you can also use [link](http://paste.ofcode.org/) this site to upload your code and share the link , no sign-up is required and code will be deleted within 7 days

Comment: Structure of code is following: <Relative Layout> EditText TextView EditText TextView </Relative Layout> In EditText height, width, left and right margin are specified and in TextView width in dp, height-wrap content, align_top and align_left aligned with corresonding EditText id.

Comment: Try these two attributes and provide proper id,        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText"

Comment: Thanks man for helping. I appreciate it.:) I will try it now.

Comment: I just tried it. Similar like combination of toLeftOf and alignTop...:(

Comment: Can you provide your compete code , + I am assuming you are using android studio , In xml layout editor choose Design tab and  you can drag these views and manually position as you like

Comment: I just pasted two different layout , understand this that you are using hard code pixel to set your layout , it will not apply to all mobile phone properly becuase all screen are of not same dimensuon I would recommend you to use TableLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using layout_margin left which is creating the problem , If your need is just this much why not use TableLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:text="Text" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText1"
            android:hint="Write..."
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_dropdown_light_frame"/>


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:text="Text" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText2"
            android:hint="Write..."
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_dropdown_light_frame"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Just copy the whole TableRow tag and paste it as many row you want

**But If you still want relative layout here's the fix code for you ** just change margin value correctly as per your need

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText1"
    android:hint="Write..."
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_dropdown_light_frame"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/TextView1" />



<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText2"
    android:hint="Write..."
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_dropdown_light_frame"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/EditText1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/EditText2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/EditText2"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/EditText2" />
```

Comment: Always happy to help and If you are using Table layout check out attributes related to table layout to for more control over layout :)

Answer (score 0):

Just arrange your XML, you can achieve what you want using padding.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">
```